# Android achartengine, Change Point Value Color

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

Is there any way to change the color of `achartengine` line graph's line point Value color from white to black?

In the below image I want to change colors 2700, 2500 etc from white to black.

Here is my code:

```
private void openChart() {

    int count = 5;
    Date[] dt = new Date[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 10, i + 1);
        dt[i] = gc.getTime();
    }

    int[] visits = {2000, 2500, 2700, 2100, 2800};

    // Creating TimeSeries for Visits
    TimeSeries visitsSeries = new TimeSeries("BMR Rate");

    // Adding data to Visits Series
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.length; i++)
        visitsSeries.add(dt[i], visits[i]);

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);

    visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(3);
    visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Body Mass Index");
    // multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{0, 0, 0, 10});
    multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    // multiRenderer.setPointSize(15);
    multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    multiRenderer.setGridColor(Color.RED);
    multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#54D66A"));
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.WHITE);
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);

    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Days");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Count");
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    // Adding visitsRenderer and viewsRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);
    //  multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(viewsRenderer);

    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

    // Creating a Time Chart
    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, "dd-MMM-yyyy");

    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    // Setting a click event listener for the graph
    mChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");

            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

            if (seriesSelection != null) {
                int seriesIndex = seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex();
                String selectedSeries = "Visits";
                if (seriesIndex == 0)
                    selectedSeries = "Visits";
                else
                    selectedSeries = "Views";

                // Getting the clicked Date ( x value )
                long clickedDateSeconds = (long) seriesSelection.getXValue();
                Date clickedDate = new Date(clickedDateSeconds);
                String strDate = formatter.format(clickedDate);

                // Getting the y value
                int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();

                // Displaying Toast Message
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        selectedSeries + " on "  + strDate + " : " + amount ,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });

    // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
    chartContainer.addView(mChart);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of just one point, you'll probably have to subclass the Renderer and set the color yourself when rendering that point.

Comment: Not one point sir. I want to change all values like wise 2000,2500,2700,2100,2800 . Is this possible sir ?

Comment: Sir which one. Please elaborate me

Comment: Sorry, got cut off... Actually, if you want the points to be different color from the line, then its the same answer - subclass the renderer. If you want the points and the line to be the same color, but something other than white, set a different color with the renderer's setColor method.

Answer (score 0):

Add colors to labels of render:

```
 multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);  
 multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: No . I don't need to set color of setYLabelsColor,setXLabelsColor . I want to change value of 2000, 2500, 2700, 2100 , White to Black